# If abstract classes can not be instantiated, exactly, what is this code: ABS clsAbs = new ABS () {

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, abstract

I have a question about abstract classes.

First of all ... I'm using the google translator, sorry :( I hope you understand.

If abstract classes can not be instantiated, exactly, what is this code:

```
public class Ppal {

public void start(){

    ABS clsAbs = new ABS() {

        @Override
        public void absMetod() {
        }
    };

    clsAbs.metod();
}
}
```

ABS:

```
public abstract class ABS{

public void metod(){}
public abstract void absMetod();

}
```

`ABS clsAbs = new ABS () {...` Is not this an instance? clsAbs can be used and
Abstract classes can not be used, only to create a model of abstraction ...

It could be used as anonymous class but this (`ABS clsAbs = new ABS () {...`) not anonymous.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 12):

You are instantiating an anonymous class that is extending the `class ABS`. And you can instantiate this anonymous class because it defines all the abstract methods in `ABS`(Thanks Nebelmann)

It is the same if you create a class like `public class Foo extends ABS` that implements the `absMetod()`

and you can do: `ABS bar = new Foo()`

Comment: And you can instantiate this anonymous class because it defines all the abstract methods in ABS.

Comment: Understood, I must see ABS clsAbs = new ABS () {... as a normal class that extends another abstract but not as an instance of ABS.
If you ask me if an abstract class can be instantiated, I will answer no. Is it correct?

Comment: Perfect! You understood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to understand is this

```
ABS clsAbs = new ABS() {

        @Override
        public void absMetod() {
        }
    };
```

you are implementing the abstract method absMetod() while creating anonymous class that  extends  `ABS` class

Comment: So, does that mean clsAbs is an anonymous class?

Comment: clsAbs is an object of anonymous class